# SysRq doesn't display any result on terminal

Tags: kernel, security, magic-sysrq, maintenance

I use Mint 19.2, and I try to see CPU backtrace by the following process.

```
    $ sudo -s
    # sysctl -w kernel.sysrq=1
    # echo l > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

But, nothing happened. I researched more online and I tried the following input key check, and the response for the command was this.

```
    # dmesg | grep -i sysrq
    [18494.528450] sysrq: SysRq : Show backtrace of all active CPUs
    [18494.528496]  sysrq_handle_showallcpus+0x17/0x20
    [18494.528499]  __handle_sysrq+0x9f/0x170
    [18494.528502]  sysrq_filter+0x98/0x3e0
```

Even when I tried `echo h > /proc/sysrq-trigger`, the result woundn't be displayed, either. But, `dmesg | grep -i sysrq` replied:

```
[21964.365327] sysrq: SysRq : HELP : loglevel(0-9) reboot(b) crash(c) terminate-all-tasks(e) memory-full-oom-kill(f) kill-all-tasks(i) thaw-filesystems(j) sak(k) show-backtrace-all-active-cpus(l) show-memory-usage(m) nice-all-RT-tasks(n) poweroff(o) show-registers(p) show-all-timers(q) unraw(r) sync(s) show-task-states(t) unmount(u) force-fb(V) show-blocked-tasks(w) dump-ftrace-buffer(z)
enter code here
```

By these `dmesg` responses, I believe the OS, at least, recognizes a letter from `echo` command as a SysRq input.

How can I have the OS display a result of `echo l > /proc/sysrq-trigger` on the current terminal?

Comment: Just to be clear, what do you mean by "the current terminal"? A text-mode Linux console (ttyX)? Or a graphical terminal emulator window such as XTerm, Gnome Terminal, Konsole?

Comment: @TooTea, Thanks for the comment. I found I was looking for an output in totally wrong format. I thought the output would be shown in GNOME terminal...

Comment: Note that, at least for me, I have to **hold** the `Alt` key, release the `SysRq` (`PrintScreen`) key, and then press the 3rd key while still holding `Alt`, in order for it to work properly...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The kernel will only display messages on the console and to the kernel message buffer, which is usually logged by syslog with facility 'kernel' and which can also be read by using `dmesg`.

The kernel has no concept of "the current terminal", so what you want is not possible.

Comment: Oh, I see. That is why...
I totally understand now. I was expecting the result would be on GNOME, and I learned it was a totally wrong intention. Thanks for the explanation :)